# Python open file cvs reader has no attribute

Tags: python, csv, scripting, reader

This is supposed to open a tab separated file and print the first row, and add them up. The column is just numbers. I have an error and also not sure how to go about adding them up afterwards.

```
with open(filePath + fileName, 'rt')  as inputfile:
    next(inputfile)
    dataArray = csv.reader(inputfile, delimiter='\t')
    for row in inputfile:
        print dataArray.split('\t',1)
```

Heres the error:

```
  File "./Medicalsys", line 38, in <module>
    print dataArray.split('\t',1)
AttributeError: '_csv.reader' object has no attribute 'split'
```

Comment: You’re mixing up three different ways of parsing the file. The whole point of a `csv.reader` is that you can just do `for row in dataArray:` and the row is _already split into a list of values_ without needing to call `split`. (But you have to do `for row in dataArray:`, not `for row in inputfile:`, for this to work.)

Comment: Alternatively, if you want to split the lines manually, get rid of the `csv.reader`, and then `for line in inputfile:` makes sense—but then you have to call `split` on the `line`, not on the whole file (or a reader wrapped around it).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to iterate dataArray as:

```
for row in dataArray:
    print(row[0])  # already split by tab by csv.reader(inputfile, delimiter='\t')
```

Comment: Thank you! Although this does print all the variables in the file, how would I just take the first column of numbers?

Comment: You're the best, thanks for all the help! It works now.